# Why does my x86 shellcode test program segfault?

Tags: linux, c, shellcode, exploit-development, x86

I am trying to learn how to create shellcode, my goal is to call `execve()`. I wrote the code in assembly and it works perfectly, there are no null-bytes or absolute addressing methods. The code works fine, but when I copy the opcodes into a c program and test it to see if it works it returns segmentation fault. What is the problem?

ASM:

```
section .text     
global _start
_start:
    jmp xxx

xx:
    mov al,11
    pop ebx
    xor ecx,ecx
    xor edx,edx
    int 0x80
    mov al,1
    xor bl,bl
    int 0x80

section .data
xxx:
    call xx
path db "/bin/sh"
```

C CODE:

```
char shellcode[]={"\xb0\x0b\x5b\x31\xc9\x31\xd2\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x30\xdb\xcd\x80"};

int main(){
    void (*ptr) (void) = &shellcode;
    ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling your C code?

Comment: gcc  -z execstack xxx.c -fno-stack-protector -no-pie --o xxx

Answer (score 21):

I see multiple problems with your shellcode. First of all let's debug your code. I compiled the C code containing your shellcode, run it with gdb and step until the first system call (`int 0x80`)

```
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
EAX: 0x5655700b --> 0xde3050f7 
EBX: 0x5655550c (<main+35>: mov    eax,0x0)
ECX: 0x0 
EDX: 0x0 
ESI: 0xf7f9fe24 --> 0x1d6d2c 
EDI: 0xf7f9fe24 --> 0x1d6d2c 
EBP: 0xffffd9d8 --> 0x0 
ESP: 0xffffd9c0 --> 0xf7fe5ae0 (<_dl_fini>: push   ebp)
EIP: 0x5655701f --> 0x1b080cd
EFLAGS: 0x246 (carry PARITY adjust ZERO sign trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x5655701a <shellcode+2>:    pop    ebx
   0x5655701b <shellcode+3>:    xor    ecx,ecx
   0x5655701d <shellcode+5>:    xor    edx,edx
=> 0x5655701f <shellcode+7>:    int    0x80
   0x56557021 <shellcode+9>:    mov    al,0x1
   0x56557023 <shellcode+11>:   xor    bl,bl
   0x56557025 <shellcode+13>:   int    0x80
   0x56557027 <shellcode+15>:   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0xffffd9c0 --> 0xf7fe5ae0 (<_dl_fini>:    push   ebp)
0004| 0xffffd9c4 --> 0x0 
0008| 0xffffd9c8 (")UUV\030pUV$\376\371\367$\376\371\367")
0012| 0xffffd9cc --> 0x56557018 --> 0x315b0bb0 
0016| 0xffffd9d0 --> 0xf7f9fe24 --> 0x1d6d2c 
0020| 0xffffd9d4 --> 0xf7f9fe24 --> 0x1d6d2c 
0024| 0xffffd9d8 --> 0x0 
0028| 0xffffd9dc --> 0xf7de3141 (<__libc_start_main+241>:   add    esp,0x10)
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
```

Here we can see a few problems:

- The `EAX` register is not set to 0xb. This is because your shellcode does not clear the values in the register and instead it just sets the lower byte with the instruction `mov al, 0xb`
- The `EBX` register should be pointing to the `char*` with the file you're trying to run (usually it's `"/bin/sh"`), instead it's pointing to a random memory position, in this case in the `main` function.
- The `ECX` register should be pointing to the array of `char*` that indicates the complete command you want to run. In most shellcodes I've seen it's just `["/bin/sh", 0]`, but you may want to use something different such as `["/path/to/binary","-argument1",..., 0]`, in this case you should create that array in memory. In your shellcode `ECX` is set to `0x0`
- The `EDX` register represents the environment for the execution of the binary. You can take a look at the [execve(3) manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execve) page to understand a bit more how it is used, but for our purpose here it's ok to have a `NULL` value in it

Now, how can we fix it? Well, first of all we'll need to point `EBX` to a "/bin/sh\0" string in a memory portion we can access, f.e. the stack. And we need to do that in our shellcode. We can do it with the following gadget:

```
xor eax, eax //Clear the eax register so we have a null byte to end our string
push eax
push "n/sh" //The string needs to be written "backwards"
push "//bi" //The double "/" is to avoid null bytes in our shellcode
mov ebx, esp //esp is pointing to "//bin/sh\0", so we need to move that pointer to ebx
```

Then we need to point `ECX` to an array of `char*` such as `["/bin/sh", 0]`. We already have a part of it in `EBX`, so continuing our shellcode we can do the following:

```
xor eax, eax 
push eax
push "n/sh"
push "//bi"
mov ebx, esp
push eax // Remember it's still 0 from our previous xor eax, eax
push ebx // Push it so ESP points to EBX
mov ecx, esp // move ESP to ECX, the result is ECX -> EBX -> "//bin/sh\0"
```

Finally, we should set the `AL` register to `0xb` and make the syscall. So our final shellcode should look like this:

```
section .text
global _start
_start:
    jmp trampoline

shellcode:
    xor eax, eax
    push eax
    push "n/sh"
    push "//bi"
    mov ebx, esp
    push eax
    push ebx
    mov ecx, esp
    mov al,11
    int 0x80

section .data
trampoline:
    call shellcode
```

We can compile it nasm `nasm -o shellcode.bin -f elf32 -O0 shellcode.nasm`, extract the opcodes and put them in the C code to test it:

```
char shellcode[] = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x2f\x62\x69\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";
int main(){
    (*(void(*)())shellcode)();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with your favorite compiler, I use gcc `gcc -o shellcode.o -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -m32 shellcode.c`. And run it:

```
$ ./shellcode.o 
sh-4.4$
```

Comment: `syscall` shouldn't be in code-formatting because the OP isn't using the `syscall` instruction (available in 32-bit user-space only on AMD CPUs).  You're using it only as shorthand for the English phrase "system call", not the instruction or the glibc wrapper function called `syscall`.

Comment: It's ok on Linux to use execve with `argv = NULL`.  I've seen that in shellcode examples before.  It's treated by the Linux kernel as equivalent to a pointer to `[NULL]` (an empty list), as documented in the man page.  Apparently some / most shells are written defensively and don't use `argv[0]` without checking that `argc>=1`.

Comment: The OP tried to get EBX pointing to a string with the old `jmp` / `call` / `pop` trick.  But they put the jump target in `.data`, and apparently omitted the `jmp` from their shellcode (as well as the `call` and string data at the end of the shellcode.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right about the syscall and didn't notice the `jmp`/`call`/`pop` trick, I'll edit the answer for the first point. About the `argv = NULL`, I've never seen a shellcode as that, do you have an example?

Comment: Just in SO questions; that's the only case I've encountered shellcode.  I'll see if I can dig up an example if I get around to it, or try it with bash on my system and see if it works.